# I don't subscribe to your laws!

Tags: riddle, rhyme

> So you think you can tame me, but I'll prove you wrong,
> My goal is to be made free, I can be quite strong.
>
> On top of your roofs, and in your alleys I move,
> Oh? I'll dispute truths, and make it so you can't prove.
>
> Try to capture me alive, I'll try to make you fail,
> Hurry! We can move in hives. See me? I'll make you yell.

What am I?

Hint:

> Humans can be me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're a

> **CRIMINAL**
>
> The first letter of each line spells **SMOOTH**, and thanks to Mr. Jackson (and AAF), 'Criminal' is the first word I think of.
>
> Lines 1-5 describe various shady deeds or actions.
>
> For line 6, my explanation was:
> H.I.V.E. is a criminal organization in the DC universe, and if you see somebody committing a crime, it could make you yell (in surprise, fright, for help, etc.)
>
> From @Joe-You-Know, the "wretched hive" trope is fairly common, stemming from Star Wars:
> "Mos Eisley Spaceport. You will never find a more wretched hive of scum and villainy."
>
> Title: Criminals break laws

Comment: I hope it isn't a stretch, this is the right answer! Rot13(Pevzvany tngurevat fcbgf ner bsgra ersreerq gb nf uvirf. "Zbf Rvfyrl Fcnprcbeg. Lbh jvyy arire svaq n zber jergpurq uvir bs fphz naq ivyynval. Jr zhfg or pnhgvbhf."— Bov-Jna Xrabov | Nyfb, gur jergpurq uvir gebcr, uggcf://gigebcrf.bet/czjvxv/czjvxv.cuc/Znva/JergpurqUvir vf snveyl pbzzba, nf vg'f gur tngurevat bs pevzvanyf.)

Comment: @Joe-You-Know Sorry, I suppose it wasn't that much of a stretch in the end.  I probably felt that way because I started with the first letters, then rationalized that it could fit the rest.  =)  Thanks for the puzzle!

Comment: Dammit, I got this yesterday but was thrown by "hive" so doubted myself.  I should have posted for my first answer attempt!

Answer (score 4):

I'm guessing this probably isn't the answer, as it doesn't quite fit everything.  Nonetheless, in case it nudges somebody else towards the actual answer, my guess is:

> A knight.

.

> My goal is to be made free, / I can be quite strong. / On top of your roofs, and in your alleys I move,

.

> Would refer to the knight piece's role in chess.  Knights can be strong if used properly, and they uniquely can jump over other pieces ("on top of your roofs" - or maybe that's a reference to the shape of the rook piece for some reason and "alleys" might be a reference to the shape of the bishop piece?).

.

> Oh? I'll dispute truths, and make it so you can't prove.

.

> This made me think of something which might have been from Lewis Carroll's mathematical writings for children or something with the same flavor: A knight (a.k.a. someone who always tells the truth in this genre) saying, "You can not prove, nor will you ever be able to prove, that this statement is true."  So, this leads into a paradox that's reminiscent of Goedel's incompleteness theorems - if it's provable then the statement is false, but the proof should contradictorily show that it's true; if it's not provable then the statement is true, but then haven't you given a proof of the statement?  ...

.

> Try to capture me alive, I'll try to make you fail.

.

> Back to chess.

The last line, though, is the one that really makes me doubt the guess.

Comment: This isn't the answer to this one. Nice guess though. I think technically, this answer has been closer to the actual answer than any other. I'll post a hint now.

Answer (score 3):

My previous guess was incorrect, and it was

> A bee?

New Guess (which may or may not be farther away than the last):

> A raccoon?

So you think you can tame me, but I'll prove you wrong,

> You can't tame raccoons, they're pretty feisty creatures

My goal is to be made free, I can be quite strong.

> They're strong, too, and don't like being trapped in cages

On top of your roofs, and in your alleys I move,

> Raccoons are commonly found in alleys, and also running on roofs

Oh? I'll dispute truths, and make it so you can't prove.

> Still no idea here

Try to capture me alive, I'll try to make you fail,

> If you try to capture a raccoon, it'll claw at you or try to break your cage

Hurry! We can move in hives. See me? I'll make you yell.

> Raccoons can spook people if they come too close or the person isn't expecting it

Secret hint:

> The first letters spell SMOOTH, which describes that raccoon from Guardians of the Galaxy? (and also both honey as well as the main bee from the Bee Movie) :)

Comment: This isn't the right answer, but it's not a bad guess. It's not something that can fly.

Comment: Thanks -- updated my answer, though I still don't think I got it.

Comment: You're a little closer. It doesn't have a tail either.

Answer (score 3):

Are you

> Electricity?

So you think you can tame me, but I'll prove you wrong,

> Electricity can't be completely tamed. Think of all the accidental shocks, electrocutions, and fires sparked by frayed electrical wires.

My goal is to be made free, I can be quite strong.

> It is always looking to "escape" from wires and sockets. It can be incrediby strong (power a city, propel a train, etc.)

On top of your roofs, and in your alleys I move,
Oh? I'll dispute truths, and make it so you can't prove.

> Electric wires run through alleys and on roofs in towns and cities. I'm not sure about the second line, other than maybe a sufficiently large shock would cause unconsciousness or memory loss.

Try to capture me alive, I'll try to make you fail,

> It is exceedingly hard to capture the electrical energy from a lightning bolt.

Hurry! We can move in hives.

> Bees live in hives and buzz. Electrical currents buzz too. (It's reaching, I know.)

See me? I'll make you yell.

> If you see a live wire shooting sparks or lightning strike nearby, you'd likely yell.

The hint

> Exciting people have been called "electric" or "electrifying."

Comment: No, not quite. But nice guess.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it is:

> bat, but -depending on spelling or pronounciation

```
So you think you can tame me, but I'll prove you wrong,
My goal is to be made free, [...]
On top of your roofs, and in your alleys I move,
[...]
Try to capture me alive, I'll try to make you fail,
Hurry! We can move in hives. See me? I'll make you yell.
```

> Refers to a wild animal

```
I can be quite strong.
```

> I guess it refers to a certain fictional superhero

```
Oh? I'll dispute truths, and make it so you can't prove.
```

> Refers to sentence conjunction or preposition 'but'

Comment: This isn't the answer, but not a bad guess. As I mentioned to El-Guest, it's not something that can fly.

Comment: @Joe-You-Know I just started to formulate an answer before seeing this comment